# ASP CORE API return JSON with a attribute that has a function as a value. (Dynamic Object)

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I create a object to return JSON with a function for one of the values of the attributes.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();
        test.paramTest = "Hello";
        test.funcTest = "() => console.log('Hello World')";

        return Ok(test);
    }
```

What I would like to return is the funcTest value is has no quotes.

```
   {
      paramTest: "Hello",
      funcTest: () => console.log('Hello World'),
   }
```

Comment: Do you need quotes like this "() => console.log('Hello World')"?

Comment: I need it without quotes..